# User control does not retain private values, returns values set in Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a control defined like:

```
public partial class MyControl: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    static int ControlID;
    static DataTable table;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ControlID = 0;
            table= new DataTable();
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        //ControlID is 0
        //table is empty DataTable
    }

    public void SetControlID(int id)
    {
        ControlID = id; //This DOES set id correctly

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SelectCommand, conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ControlID ", ControlID);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(table);

        //table is correctly filled with the correct data
    }
}
```

This control is added to my `aspx` page like:

```
<uc:MyControl ID="myCont" runat="server" />
```

In `Page_Load` is the call:

```
myCont.SetControlID(1); //This correctly calls the `SetControlID` method and 
                        //seems to fill the `table` and set `ControlID` to 1.
```

However there is a "Save" button on the page that calls:

```
myCont.Save();
```

In this method, checking `ControlID` and `table` shows them as still being 0 and an empty `DataTable` respectively.

Why do `ControlID` and `table` not retain the values that were set in the `SetControlID` method?

**EDIT:** Removing the static property of the 2 variable makes no difference.

**EDIT #2:** I'd just like to point out I have used this method in numerous other pages and everything is working fine. What is so different with this one?

Comment: Might be because of Static property. Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4s70936s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Exactly. Why are those two variables static?

Comment: They were set as static because I was having issues with other pages where variables were not being initialised at all. Setting it to `static` worked so I kept the practice going. But as the edit above says, removing the `static` property makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preserve the data, you have to use [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fb3w5b53%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
public partial class MyControl: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
   public int ControlID
   {
     get
       {
        if(ViewState["ControlID"]==null)
           return 0;
        return int.Parse(ViewState["ControlID"].ToString()); 
       }
     set
      {
        ViewState["ControlID"] = value;
      }
   }
  ....
 }
```

Comment: I have accepted this as it is what worked. I don't understand how other pages, that use similar logic, work without using `ViewState`. When I say other pages, I mean over numerous applications I have built before, not just this application.

Answer (score 4):

In ASP.NET, lifecycle of a Page class is for duration of processing request.  That is when request comes in, the class for the page is instantiated, viewstate is deserialized to restore state (if it is Postback), an event is ran (like button click), response generated, and object is then destroyed.  Thus any member that does not save its state into viewstate (such as int) will not be retained across activations.

Also, a suspect in your code are that ControlID and tabe are both declared static.  That means those values will be shared amongst all callers of the page (and every time a fresh page is requested, table will be overwritten for all users).  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I accepted AVD's post below due to the code provided but did upvote yours. The `static` thing is not the issue, `ViewState` does work. What I don't understand how other pages, that use similar logic, work without using `ViewState`. When I say other pages, I mean over numerous applications I have built before, not just this application.

Answer (score 2):

`static` variables are not page level (instance level).. EVERY time the page is loaded for any other user etc your static `table` will be reset to an empty table.  Very bad bad bad idea.

Comment: I understand the implications of `static` variable, but this was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I should write this as a comment to the answer that you have accepted. But, I don't have enough reputation points to comment :-)

> *I have accepted this as it is what worked. I don't understand how other pages, that use similar logic, work without using ViewState.
>   When I say other pages, I mean over numerous applications I have built
>   before, not just this application. -anothershrubery*

I would also recommend to use viewstate in this case as static members are shared across all web request sessions, so, potentially you may see unwanted behavior.

As you were wondering why your code didn't work, I'll try to give you a reasoning:

Refer ASP.NET page life cycle [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/01/14/asp-net-page-life-cycle-diagram.aspx)... From this you could observe that User Control's load event processed after Page's load event. So, program flow goes like this:

1. In Page's `Page_Load`, you are calling `myCont.SetControlID(1)` which sets ControlID & table
2. Then User Control's `Page_Load` happens, in which you are resetting/initializing ControlID & table.
3. At later point `myCont.Save()` gets called, in which you would see reset values for ControlID & table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You say the `myCont.Save()` resets the values, which I can see and I can follow the logic, but the same logic I used here has been used in many other pages in this application and others and it works. I'm more wondering why the other ones work, surely they should fall foul of this as well?

Comment: Reset happens in User Control's `Page_Load`, and by the time User Control's `Save` method gets called the values have already been reset-ted. I can't comment on why the same code at other places worked until I have more information on them. May be the other places do not have values reset-ted in **User Control's `Page_Load`**